# Cannot set icon Image in Raylib using C++

Tags: c++, raylib

I'm making a little game using [**raylib**](https://www.raylib.com/) in C++. I am trying to set the window icon using [`SetWindowIcon(icon)`](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/334e96d470c5cb09d154e1c849d04adb721a7a8c/src/raylib.h#L953), but it doesn't actually set the icon:

```
const int screenWidth = 1000;
const int screenHeight = 800;
InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "BulletProof"); 
const char* gameDirectory = GetWorkingDirectory();
std::string iconPath = std::string(gameDirectory) + "/icon.ico";
Image icon = LoadImage(iconPath.c_str());
SetWindowIcon(icon);
```

It does not give any error while compiling, and the game opens succesfuly, but icon is not changed. My icon is on `.ico` format. (I also tried a `.png` format image, but that also did not work).

Comment: Random guess: the working directory is not the same as the one where your icon is.

Comment: Unrelated: Capital letters are used on the first word of a sentence, not every word.

Comment: @Botje ,Well I Think It's False, Because I Load Player Sprite(`Player.png`) Using Same Function And It Works.

Comment: Hence why I marked it as "random guess". This is the most common reason for external resources not being usable. If you included that information in your post we wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Next best thing is to whip out the debugger and step into `SetWindowIcon`, I guess.

Comment: // Set icon for window (only PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
// NOTE 1: Image must be in RGBA format, 8bit per channel
// NOTE 2: Image is scaled by the OS for all required sizes (This Is What Is Written In Definiton, I'll Try RGBA Format)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get mine to work.

```
Image icon = LoadImage("Icon_path_directory.png");
SetWindow(icon);
UnloadImage(icon); // Needed if continuously loaded.
```

I double checked that my png image is in RGBA pixel format by right clicking and making sure it has an Alpha (A8) channel in properties. I couldn't get .ico file to work, other examples seem to use png. I used Photoshop to make my png, others have used Gimp. Just be sure the background is removed and double check save options for Alpha channel.